# JNI CallFloatMethod implementation

Tags: java, java-native-interface

where can I find the implementation (source code) of the CallFloatMethod function? I'm trying to figure out if this function uses the Java reflection API.

Comment: It's the other way around. The Java Reflection API uses this method, when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with the sources do following:

1. Get the source code of JDK

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk12u/
https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk12u/archive/tip.tar.gz

2. Unpack it
3. Find the method

   find . -name "*.cpp" -exec grep -H -n "CallFloatMethod" {} \;